# How to do the support after delivery?

Tags: client-support, clients

Myself and customer agreed on a support period after delivery, for the application testing is done and for reports also is done, but this test performed with demo data not actual live data (Application is Time Attendance system which need to be configured as customer's clients) so how to tell the customer nicely that any issue in UAT is within the report delivery and after fixing issues captured in UAT is support.

I'm asking this becasue I've a payment after deliver the reports itself, so how to declare the issues captured in UAT and issues captured after UAT.

Comment: Hey Emad, welcome to Freelancing SE. Can you clarify this a bit more. Are you wanting the client to do the testing or are you asking the client for data so you can do the testing? That's not quite clear. As an aside, developers should do verification testing on their own, without production data, but that's another issue altogether...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I went ahead and opened this back up. Sounds like the problem is you want to convey to the customer that the time you're now spending is billable time? Sounds like you got paid for the development but now want to bill for the support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom line is support includes things which you to agree upon. Try searching the net for term "Retainer Agreement". Basically, a client buys certain number of work hours and during those hours, you should (or must, based on the agreement) be available 24/7 to immediately start fixing bugs or code add-ons.

Since this is a vast area, you should read it and then ask a more concrete question.